# Can I use a function to return two values?

Tags: excel, vba

can I use a function that returns 2 values of type `Double` and `Boolean`?

```
Function FindLoop(arr, val, bol, x) As Double
    Dim r As Double, c As Double
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(r, c) = val Then
                FindLoop = c
                Exit Function
            End If
            If c = UBound(arr, 2) Then
                FindLoop = False
                FindLoop = x
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you provided some context to your function. You could also], show sample input with desired output? The quality of the answer is usually hinged on the quality of the question.

Comment: You could return an array of two values, an instance of a custom Type or Class, or use ByRef parameters and set their values inside the function (which in that last case could be a Sub)  A lot would depend   on how you're calling the function - from a worksheet for example?

Answer (score 3):

You can a `ByRef` parameter of type `Double` to your function and set its value before returning the `Boolean` value:

```
Function FindLoop(ByVal arr, ByVal val, ByVal bol, ByVal x, ByRef result As Double) As Boolean
    Dim r As Double, c As Double
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(r, c) = val Then
                result = c
                FindLoop = ' TODO: return a boolean value
                Exit Function
            End If
            If c = UBound(arr, 2) Then
                result = x
                FindLoop = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim result As Double
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = FindLoop(arr, val, bol, x, result)
    If found Then
        ' Returned True. Use the result value here.
    Else
        ' Returned False. Use or discard the result value.
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`ByRef` works, as @Ahmed Abdelhameed showed. There's also the possibilty to use a User Defined Type (`Type/EndType`), which I find a cleaner solution.

In a module:

```
Public Type MyType
   Value1 As Long
   Value2 As Boolean
End Type

Function MyFunction(ByVal Param1 As Long, ByVal Param2 As Boolean) As MyType

   Dim udt As MyType

   With udt
      .Value1 = Param1
      .Value2 = Param2
   End With

   MyFunction = udt

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim udt As MyType

udt = MyFunction(1, True)
Debug.Print udt.Value1, udt.Value2 ' Results in "1 True"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Variant` output type:

```
Function FindLoop(arr, val, bol, x) As Variant
```

and then handle it appropriately, for instance (using a testing function for demonstrative purposes):

```
Function myf(val As String) As Variant
    If val = "a" Then
        myf = True
    Else
        myf = 1.2
    End If
End Function


Sub test()
    If TypeName(myf("a")) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "return type is a boolean"
    Else
        MsgBox "return type is a double"
    End If
End Sub
```